# HtmlAgilityPack Metro Version?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, html-agility-pack

I'm a little new to the WinRT world, but I already figured out that some of the old libs don't work on Metro anymore, because of the new WinRT Runtime.
Now I wanted to convert some old Project with HtmlAgilityPack to Metro. The old lib didn't work, so I got the newest from Nuget. Which unfortunately is not compatible with the old one. Funny enough, after I updated my old project with the newest Version from Nuget (exactly the same one), it still had the old functions in it.

Can you support two different runtimes in the same package? How does that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NuGet allows you to include versions for different .NET Framework Versions:

[Supporting Multiple .NET Framework Versions and Profiles](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package#Supporting_Multiple_.NET_Framework_Versions_and_Profiles)

Which is used a lot (e.g. JSON.NET has this) to use different assemblies for net20/net35/net40/net45 or for silverlight/winrt

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to convert HtmlAgilityPack to metro as someone already did.

I have used it and it work great.

http://fizzlerex.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Didn't know that. But HtmlAgilityPack already works on Metro, just in a bit a limited way. I was more surprised on how to achieve this and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand the question. I would Add the new Library and refactor my old code to work with the new library. Otherwise you will have 2 libraries with the same namespace in the same project... which isn't going to work.